# Package Check Failed: Oracle DB 11g on RHEL 7

Tags: linux, oracle

Trying to install Oracle DB 11g EE on RHEL 7. Installed the necessary packages as mentioned in the below link [(Section 6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCGJCEA)).

But I am stuck at the package check step, which fails because it couldn't find earlier versions of the packages.

Ex of one of the package error:

**![Error Snippet of one particular package]**

- `Expected Value: libaio-0.3.105 (i386)`

Also, when I try to install the required package, the repo doesn't find those versions. If I ignore, I am getting the below error.

**![Snippet: Stuck here]**

- `Error in Invoking target "client_sharedlib" of makefile '<path>/product/11.2.0/db_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'.`

Stuck here. Please help.

**List of other packages getting failed:**

- libaio-0.3.105
- compat-libstdc++-33-3.3.3
- compat-libstdc++-33-3.3.3 (twice)
- libaio-devel-0.3.105
- libgcc-3.4.6
- libstdc++-3.4.6
- unixODBC-2.2.11
- unixODBC-devel-2.2.11
- pdksh-5.2.14

Exact versions:

- OracleDB: Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0)
- RHEL: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)

Comment: Added the link. OracleDB: Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0) and RHEL: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)

Comment: Oops! 11g link I followed is here. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCGJCEA

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/pre_install.htm#LADBI1110) 11g is supported on RHEL 4 and RHEL 5.  If you want 11g you'll need to install an older version of the OS, or do a lot of Linux hacking.  Alternatively you could install Oracle 12c, which is supported on RHEL 7 (11g is now an unsupported version, although I appreciate that probably doesn't bother you).

Comment: But as per the link I shared, it says possible to install on RHEL 7 right ?

Comment: @APC, For 11g on RHEL7, it must be `11.2.0.4`. However, I would go for 12c rather than 11g.

Answer (score 1):

From **My Oracle support**, [Doc ID 1304727.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=178186440167401&id=1304727.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=aom0hw9a0_4)

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 - 11.2.0.4 only
>
> - Oracle Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel:3.8.13-35.3.1.el7uek.x86_64 or higher
> - Red Hat compatible kernel: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 or higher

So, unless you are installing `11.2.0.4`, you will have compatibility issues on `RHEL7`. Either install 11.2.0.4 and up on RHEL7, or use a lower compatible version.

More information:

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.x  - Database 11.2.0.3 and higher
>
> - Red Hat kernel 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 or later
> - Oracle Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel (UEK R1) 2.6.32-100.28.5.el6.x86_64 or later

Comment: So, does WCS 11.1.1.8.0 on WLS 10.3.6.0 supported by 12c DB ?

Comment: @PrabhuR Could you please elaborate, I didn't get you.

Comment: If I install 12c version, will WebCenterSites on WebLogic Server be supportive?

Comment: @PrabhuR But how is this related to your original question? You should post a new question for weblogic server related. I have 12c installed on OEL7, I have no issues with weblogic, everything works fine.

Comment: I tried 11.2.0.4 version. Package checks went fine. But I am getting this error while installing: "Error in Invoking target "client_sharedlib" of makefile '<path>/product/11.2.0/db_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk' ". Please help.